# How can we show excel and doc files in angular6

Tags: excel, angular, html, pdf, doc

I am using outlook mail api to receive and show mail content which can also include attachments of any type. I had managed to show pdf files using pdf-view module but for excel and doc files no such module or anything exist.Could anyone suggest something for this.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So what I found from my research is you can not display a word file using java script or angular, it only opens up a dialog box to download the file.

As an alternate what you can do is convert word file to HTML and preview it in browser. Mammoth.JS is the best option for this.